# How can I cleanly order data in the desired sequence within Power BI Visualizations? (Line and Stacked Column Chart)

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I am working on a report that displays monthly data most of which are represented in the following format, XX+YY (IE 01+11,02+10,03+09, etc.).  The first set of digits reflect the represented month, so these naturally order themselves in sequence.

[Image of visual with correct sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5kHq.png)

However, I must also include the financial plan for the year is in the format "FYXX Plan" where XX is the last two digits of the calendar year.  When sorting text Power BI orders leading numbers before leading letters, so this moves the plan column to the END of the data set instead of where it logically belongs at the FRONT.

[Image of visual with incorrect sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOUrP.png)

Is it possible to re-order my visual to still show the XX+YY monthly data in ascending order, but to move the FYXX Plan data to be the first column shown?

Very respectfully,

Jon J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a new column for sorting, stripping out the 'FY' when it exists e.g.

`SortColumn = IFERROR(mid(Sorting[Date],find("FY",Sorting[Date])+2,10),Sorting[Date])`
(For any value which includes 'FY' the mid function will show the remaining characters, if FY is not found it will error, and give the full date,  there are a number of ways to achieve this using e.g. `IF` statements etc.

You can either replace the axis with this column, if you really need it to display as 'FYxx' you could set First(SortColumn) as the tooltip text to allow you to sort by that instead.

[image: PowerBI chart sorted as described in question]